# Replacing old Windows agents for TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

We have a TeamCity installation which we have just upgraded from 8.0.1 to 2017.1.1. Everything when very smooth and plainless. 
However, we seem to have a problem with our agents, which SEEM to be slower now than before.

The current agents (all virtual on an inhouse VMWare ESXi 6 server) are running Windows 7 32-bit and has not been re-installed or undergone significant maintenance in more than 6 years. I was not the one to do the original installation, so I do not have the full history of the agents, although it is close.

In the beginning the access to the agents was somewhat of the wild west, and thus they are not as alike as I would like. 
So, I am thinking of creating new agents and replace the old ones, but am having some questions regarding this.

We develop almost exclusively in .NET with a few licensed third-party products, so the setup of an agent should be relatively simple. We do have a few legacy .NET Compact Edition 3.5 builds, but otherwise it is more or less regular Visual Studio solutions ranging from .NET 3.5 to 4.6. Many solutions are Silverlight.

I am aware of the issue with the missing Microsoft.WebApplication.targets without Visual Studio installed, and have no problem with manually copying the files.

I am thinking about basing the agents on Windows 10 64-bit, but would it be better with 32-bit?

I intend to install the following packages, at least:

- .NET Framework 3.5 (Optional Windows component on Windows 10).
- .NET Framework 4.6 (Default Windows component on Windows 10).
- Windows SDK 7.0
- Windows SDK 7.1
- Windows SDK 8.0
- Windows SDK 8.1
- Windows SDK 10.0 or 10.1.
- Microsoft Build Tools 2013
- Microsoft Build Tools 2015
- Microsoft Build Tools 2017
- Silverlight 5 SDK
- Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5

The two Windows component should cover .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 and 4.6. But will I need to install some or all of these separately?

How about 4.5.1 and 4.5.2? 
How about 4.6.1 and 4.6.2? 
Is there anything else, that I should be aware of? 
Is it a good idea to use 64-bit agents? 
Will there be issues on older target systems? 
Any caveats I need to be aware of?

I hope someone will take the time to answer some or all of my questions.

Thank you.